# How can an image of unknown size be centered within a div of known size?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to centre an image of unknown size within a div of known size, such that the image is centered both vertically and horizontally within the div and the aspect ratio of the image is not distorted.

Here's an [example](http://tinyurl.com/27p85bh)

This code almost does the job but both images look shifted down slightly... by maybe a couple of pixels. Why?

The HTML;

```
<body>
  <div class="container" id="c1">
    <img src="test.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="c2">
    <img src="test.jpg"/>
  </div>
</body>
```

The CSS;

```
.container {
 text-align: center;   /* Center the image horizontally */
 margin: 1em;  /* Just for looks */
 background: red; /* Just for looks */
}

.container img {
 vertical-align: middle;    /* See note below */
 max-height: 100%;   /* Limit the image size to fit the container */
 max-width: 100%;   /* Limit the image size to fit the container */
}

#c1 {
 width: 8em;
 height: 4em;   /* See note below */
 line-height: 4em;  /* See note below */
}

#c2 {
 width: 5em;
 height: 7em;   /* See note below */
 line-height: 7em;  /* See note below */
}
```

Note: The image is vertically centered within the container by making the line-height of the container the same as the height of the container, and applying {vertical-align: middle;} to the image. This should vertically center the image within the container and it almost works, except that the image is always two pixels too low.

I've tried doing * {margin:0; padding:0} and several reset.css files but still the image appears to be shifted down a bit.

So my question is really two questions;

1. How can an image of unknown size be centered within a div of known size?
2. Why is there a small gap between the img and the edge of the div?

Regards, a CSS newbie.

Comment: is it me or is the HTML not all there?

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy Fixed that, not indented properly.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I could come up with is to use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('img').each(
            function(){
                var imgHeight = $(this).height()/2;
                var imgWidth = $(this).width()/2;
                var div = $(this).parent();
                var divHeight = div.height()/2;
                var divWidth = div.width()/2;
                $(this).css(
                    {
                        'top':divHeight - imgHeight,
                        'left':divWidth - imgWidth
                    });
            });
    });
```

I'm not, however, convinced that this is the most streamlined way. On the plus side, though, it works: [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TzCwE/2/).

Comment: +1 Horizontal centring can be achieved via CSS, but this height method is sensible.

Comment: @Orbling: horizontal-centring can be (normally) taken care of in css, but since I was using `position: absolute;` on the `img` elements I was under the impression the element was taken out of the document's flow, and therefore couldn't be centered using `margin: 0 auto;` (or, indeed, `text-align: center` on the parent `div` element).

Comment: To make this a bit more general you could use `$(this).closest(".container")` instead of `$(this).parent()`. That way you can enclose the image inside another element within the container.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS3 and the flexible box model if you don't mind some browser inconsistencies:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one">One</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    background: rgb(230,230,230);
    display: -moz-box; -moz-box-orient: horizontal; -moz-box-pack: center; -moz-box-align: center;
    display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; -webkit-box-pack: center; -webkit-box-align: center;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
#container #one {
    background: rgb(200,200,200);
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/brandondurham/q7feV/

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "browser inconsistencies"? I'm looking for something that will work with IE6 and above.

Comment: Browser inconsistencies... let me think... er... IE = naff, any other well known browser = brilliant. Basically either other browsers exclude padding, margin and border in the width / height of an element, and IE includes padding, margin and border, or it may be the other way round. I can't remember which way round it is - been ages since I had to code for IE.

Comment: One other thing - @Brandon: spot has asked that the container be flexible in width and height too. I *think* this can be achieved by removing the width / height settings for #container, but I am not sure. I know #one appears in the middle of the box (horizontally) when those are removed.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't utilize CSS3 as currently about 64% of our visitors have either IE6, IE7 or IE8.

Answer (score 0):

You should know the image's width to place it to center, using margin: auto CSS property of the div. I guess the javascript is the only solution for your problem if its width is unknown

Comment: jQuery would be better - I have managed to do something like this quite easily, but I had several lines of text (product code, name, description etc) below the image. I don't have the code open at the moment, but the next time I do (probably later on tonight) I will post my solution. PS I know it sounds like I am saying jQuery is different to JS altogether - but I do know it is JS-based... :)

Comment: The horizontal centering of the image within the container works ok. It's done by .container { text-align: center;}

Comment: I guess you're right, because the img is an inline element... (I've checked it :))

Answer (score 0):

On image's onload event you should take its width and height then resize the image keeping aspect ratio then centeralize the image using JavaScript.

Please check the following example that I've done previously for test purpose.

[Proportional image resize on image load and displays a loading gif until image load](http://www.fatihacet.com/lab/imageload)

Comment: That's exactly the effect I'm looking for. If I have to resort to a script I will do but I'd prefer a CSS-only solution. But thanks for the script and great example.

Comment: You can not do that with pure CSS. You need to know image's width and height. Maybe you can use CSS expressions for that but it is not recommended. In everywhere I read "avoid CSS Expressions" for performance. If your site has limited number of guest you may use it. If you interested in I can help you. Just comment here..

Answer (score 0):

Use "margin:auto;" on the image to center it horizontally within the div.

To center vertically "vertical-align" won't work. If the containers are positioned elements you could use "top:50%" "margin-top: - (half the height of the image)" but since you don't know the height you will need to calculate it using javascript.

Comment: The horizontal centering is done by .container {text-align: center;} and it works fine. The vertical centering is done by virtue of the fact that an image is an inline element so a combination of .container img {vertical-align: middle;} and making the line-height of the container the same as the height of the container ie. #c1 {height: 4em; line-height: 4em;} almost works. The only slight problem is that the img always looks shifted down by a couple of pixels.

Comment: If you could provide an example page where you have used this then I would be grateful. It sounds to me like you have the effect you are looking for except that you have to specify the height, but you don't know where the extra couple of pixels at the top come from. This could come from several things - container padding, container margin and image margin (and possibly image padding if that is possible - but I don't think it is). Also, if the border of the image or the container is the same colour as the element it is in front of then it looks like there is no border. Try setting border: 0.